# Python : Base64 Decode codec can't decode bytes in position 47-48 : invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, base64, decode

I found many questions related to this question on stackoverflow and even following and applying what solved problems for other users. I'm still at starting line.

I'm receiving response in UTF-8 encoded format. It's XML file I want to decode.
I saved the response in .txt file saved as UTF-8 encoding and tried following :

```
import base64

with open('docdata.txt', 'r') as f:
    e = f.read()

print(e[:50])

decoded = base64.b64decode(e)
print(str(decoded, "utf-8"))
```

When I run above program I get this error:

```
  print(str(decoded, "utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 47-48: invalid continuation byte
```

File size is around 26MB. When I tried uploading the same file on [Base64decode](https://www.base64decode.org/) I am getting proper output file without any error.

```
     print(decoded[:50])    
   >> b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x005O=Q\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00newUserPkList.xml\xec\xbd\xcb'
     
   print(decoded[47:50]
   >> b'\xec\xbd\xcb'
```

Please let me know what mistake I'm doing and how can I solve this error ?

Thanks.

Comment: The file isn't a UTF-8-encoded text file.  `PK` indicates .ZIP file.

Comment: the response that I received should I save it as .zip and then unzip it using unzip module and then proceed with utf-8 decoding ?

Comment: The response headers likely indicate the course of action.